# How to mount windows 10 drive on WSL home directory?

Tags: linux, windows-10, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to mount drive D on /home directory in WSL while letting C drive to be mounted on /mnt or not mounting it at all. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. There is a [setting to mount manually](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/02/07/automatically-configuring-wsl/) instead of automount.

To disable `[automount]` I should set `enable` key in `wsl.conf` to `false`.
Here is my `/etc/wsl.conf`:

```
[automount]
enabled=false
mountFsTab=true
```

Also, I should have added the following line to `fstab`.

```
D:  /home   drvfs   defaults    0 0
```

and it did work. Just do not forget to have `.bashrc` and `.profile` in your D drive.

Comment: Does Windows 10 has to be up to a certain version? I have version 1709 (OS Build 16299.1268), with these in /etc/wsl.conf:

 [automount] //
 enabled = false //
 mountFsTab = true //

... and an /etc/fstab file, it doesn't seem to work.